# Update Preview Error

Tags: 2013, siteedit

I am getting the below error when I click the "Update Preview" button after making content changes in the Experience Manager in SDL Tridion 2013. I am not sure what is causing this. Thanks in advance :

```xml
((Unable to update the changes using OData Service. An error occurred while processing this request.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?> 
<error xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata"
 xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
 xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/06/edmx"
 xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices"
 xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata"> 
<code></code> 
<message xml:lang="en-US">The input data was invalid: Content field required., 
  Content field required., Content field required.</message> 
</error>))
```

This is the Log details:

> 2014-05-21 10:05:21,296 DEBUG SessionServiceImpl - Loadin...2014-05-21 10:05:21,296 DEBUG SessionServiceImpl - Loading previewSessionItems and previewSessionPublicationMappings for session ff7cdee1-100b-4166-9699-07e1e39a4341.
>
> 2014-05-21 10:05:21,296 DEBUG JPAPreviewSessionItemDAO - Retrieving PreviewSessionItems by sessionId: ff7cdee1-100b-4166-9699-07e1e39a4341.
>   2014-05-21 10:05:21,296 DEBUG JPAPublicationMappingDAO - Retrieving PublicationMapping by mappingKey: ff7cdee1-100b-4166-9699-07e1e39a4341.
>
> 2014-05-21 10:05:21,312 DEBUG JPAItemDAO - Removing binary meta from storage
>
> 2014-05-21 10:05:21,328 ERROR SessionWrapperFactory - Exception while cleaning-up session data: Error while committing the transaction, Error while committing the transaction
>
> 2014-05-21 10:06:20,948 DEBUG HttpModule - Dispose
>       8:20 AM

Comment: I would go and set the log level for the OData webservice to DEBUG, then try again - this will actually write the content that the CM is trying to POST to OData, and then you can try to figure out what's wrong with it. See here for a sequence of events after clicking Update Preview: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10802033/866454
Content Required suggests your templates are not generating the content/output correctly when executed in Preview mode.

Comment: The error you just posted seems unrelated to the error message you mention - I would expect to see an Error with the same cause (Content field required)... This log seems to be from the web application (Staging) rather than from the webservice.

Comment: The logs are not getting created now. It was last updated on 5/21. I had updated the logback from Error to Debug mode on 5/21 and the above were logged. But now when I am trying nothing is getting logged. Now I am having the logging issue along with site edit, please guide on what should I check to restart the logging service.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that you changed the schema? When a schema is changed and components using that schema are not yet updated (openend and saved again), you can see strange errors,sometimes.